# Trying to figure out how the best way to use TSQL to retrieve current date but have a time value hard coded for select queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, syntax, ssms

Currently I am looking for a way to avoid hard coding date values for select queries I seek to automate.  Ideally my queries will run daily on a report server, so I want the day to change automatically but I would like to specify the time values the date function uses.  Example of hard coded value is below.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [xxxx].[dbo].[LOADS]
WHERE NOT STATUS = '' AND LOCATION LIKE 'C0%' AND 
EDITDATE <= '2018-01-19 00:00:00.000'  
ORDER BY EDITDATE DESC
```

I know I can use this SYSDATETIME function to grab current date and time.  This is helpful but I want to specify the time values.  Any thoughts or assistance would be greatly appreciated.  The main idea is to have the query run by itself automated so the date will change based on T-SQL syntax but I would like to specify the time values.

```
    SELECT * 
FROM [xxxx].[dbo].[LOADS]
WHERE NOT STATUS = '' AND LOCATION LIKE 'C0%' AND EDITDATE <= SYSDATETIME()  
ORDER BY EDITDATE DESC
```

Comment: do you actually want midnight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually want midnight 00:00:00.000, like in your example, casting as a date will strip the time, then you can cast back to a datetime. This conversion gives you midnight.

```
CAST(CAST(SYSDATETIME() as Date) as DateTime)
```

If not that gives you a starting point to `DATEADD`

```
DATEADD(hh,8,CAST(CAST(SYSDATETIME() as Date) as DateTime))
```

That's 8 am.

If you want midnight just leave it as a date, based on your where clause that will work fine - a datetime on the date will match >=

```
SELECT * 
FROM [xxxx].[dbo].[LOADS]
WHERE NOT STATUS = '' AND LOCATION LIKE 'C0%' AND EDITDATE <= CAST(SYSDATETIME() as Date) 
ORDER BY EDITDATE DESC
```

Comment: Thank you both very much! I really appreciate the assistance.  I hope you have an excellent weekend.

Comment: Andrew, hope your having a good afternoon sir.  I was wondering how I could go about  writing the where clause to get tomorrows date with the time values as '00:00:00.000' I was trying to use something like                                                                        select DATEADD(day, +1, convert(date, GETDATE())) returns tomorrows date but having a hard time getting the time values concatenated/added.  Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Thomas just do the convert/cast last `CAST(DATEADD(D, 1,  GETDATE()) AS DATE)` That will give you tomorrows date as `yyyy-mm-dd` which should work for you, since a date with no time will function as if the time was 00:00:00.000 midnight, if you want that explicit just cast it back.

Comment: Andrew FTW!!!! Thanks man, I also wrote it out this way and it seemed to run okay.                                                                                         
select DATEADD(hh,24,CAST(CAST(SYSDATETIME() as Date) as DateTime)) I am definitely going to try your way as well.  It is helping me understand how the system wants to see the datatypes and how to manipulate them.  You Rock!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a time component to a `datetime`.  I would suggest something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [xxxx].[dbo].[LOADS]
WHERE STATUS <> '' AND
      LOCATION LIKE 'C0%' AND 
      EDITDATE <= cast(cast(sysdatetime() as date) as datetime)+ cast('03:04:05' as datetime)
ORDER BY EDITDATE DESC ;
```

This would be for 3:04:05 a.m. on the current date.

Comment: Gordon, hope your having a good afternoon sir. I was wondering how I could go about writing the where clause to get tomorrows date with the time values as '00:00:00.000' I was trying to use something like select DATEADD(day, +1, convert(date, GETDATE())) returns tomorrows date but having a hard time getting the time values concatenated/added. Any thoughts or help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Thomas . . . Questions should be asked as questions and not in comments.

Comment: Thank you, I will make sure to adhere.  I am new to the community but want to make sure I abide by the rules.